# Compressed app (.ipa) larger in Xcode 4 than Xcode 3?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

I recently switched to Xcode 4 (from Xcode 3), and noticed that the size of the compressed app files I'm generating jumped by > 3MB.  I tried building it on Xcode 3 using the same project file as in Xcode 4, and there's still a size discrepancy.

What should be my next step in debugging this?  Are there particular Xcode settings or preferences I should check?  How about project preferences that might be interpreted differently depending on the version of Xcode?

Comment: Are you inadvertently building your app in debug mode on Xcode 4 perhaps?

Comment: Have you cleaned up your project prior to compilation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are building a fat binary for two architectures.

Check the 'Architectures' option in the 'Build Settings' tab of you project.
If it is set to 'Standard', Xcode will include binaries for both armv6 and armv7. Change it to 'Optimized', and Xcode will build for armv7 only. I think, Apple is using armv7 since the iPhone 3GS and 3rd generation iPod touch.

Comment: This did not turn out to be relevant to the project I was asking about, but has proven to be very useful in the project I'm working on now. :-)